# Why do Maps have slower lookup property than Records in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm reading Programming Erlang, in Chapter 5 of the book it says:

> Records are just tuples in disguise, so they have the same storage and performance
>   characteristics as tuples. Maps use more storage than tuples and have
>   slower lookup properties.

In languages I've learned before, this is not the case. Maps are usually implemented as a Hash Table, so the lookup time complexity is `O(1)`; Records (Tuples with names) are usually implemented as an immutable List, and the lookup time complexity is `O(N)`.

What's different in the implementation of these data structures in Erlang?

Comment: For Erlang/OTP 24 and newer, please see the [maps chapter of the Erlang Efficiency Guide](https://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/maps.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's no real practical performance difference between record lookup and map lookup for small numbers of fields. For large numbers of fields, though, there is, because record information is known at compile time while map keys need not be, so maps use a different lookup mechanism than records. But records and maps are not intended as interchangeable replacements, and so comparing them for use cases involving anything more than a small number of fields is pointless IMO; if you know the fields you need at compile time, use records, but if you don't, use maps or another similar mechanism. Because of this, the following focuses only on the differences in performance of looking up one record field and one map key.

Let's look at the assembler for two functions, one that accesses a record field and one that accesses a map key. Here are the functions:

```
-record(foo, {f}).

r(#foo{f=X}) ->
    X.

m(#{f := X}) ->
    X.
```

Both use pattern matching to extract a value from the given type instance.

Here's the assembly for `r/1`:

```
{function, r, 1, 2}.
  {label,1}.
    {line,[{location,"f2.erl",6}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,f2},{atom,r},1}.
  {label,2}.
    {test,is_tuple,{f,1},[{x,0}]}.
    {test,test_arity,{f,1},[{x,0},2]}.
    {get_tuple_element,{x,0},0,{x,1}}.
    {get_tuple_element,{x,0},1,{x,2}}.
    {test,is_eq_exact,{f,1},[{x,1},{atom,foo}]}.
    {move,{x,2},{x,0}}.
    return.
```

The interesting part here starts under `{label,2}`. The code verifies that the argument is a tuple, then verifies the tuple's arity, and extracts two elements from it. After verifying that the first element of the tuple is equal to the atom `foo`, it returns the value of the second element, which is record field `f`.

Now let's look at the assembly of the `m/1` function:

```
{function, m, 1, 4}.
  {label,3}.
    {line,[{location,"f2.erl",9}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,f2},{atom,m},1}.
  {label,4}.
    {test,is_map,{f,3},[{x,0}]}.
    {get_map_elements,{f,3},{x,0},{list,[{atom,f},{x,0}]}}.
    return.
```

This code verifies that the argument is a map, then extracts the value associated with map key `f`.

The costs of each function come down to the costs of the assembly instructions. The record function has more instructions but it's likely they're less expensive than the instructions in the map function because all the record information is known at compile time. This is especially true as the key count for the map increases, since that means the `get_map_elements` call has to potentially wade through more map data to find what it's looking for.

We can write functions to call these accessors numerous times, then time the new functions. Here are two sets of recursive functions that call the accessors `N` times:

```
call_r(N) ->
    call_r(#foo{f=1},N).
call_r(_,0) ->
    ok;
call_r(F,N) ->
    1 = r(F),
    call_r(F,N-1).

call_m(N) ->
    call_m(#{f => 1},N).
call_m(_,0) ->
    ok;
call_m(M,N) ->
    1 = m(M),
    call_m(M,N-1).
```

We can call these with `timer:tc/3` to check the execution time for each function. Let's call each one ten million times, but do so 50 times and take the average execution time. First, the record function:

```
1> lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f2,call_r,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
237559.02
```

This means calling the function ten million times took an average of 238ms. Now, the map function:

```
2> lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f2,call_m,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
235871.94
```

Calling the map function ten million times averaged 236ms per call. Your mileage will vary of course, as did mine; I observed that running each multiple times sometimes resulted in the record function being faster and sometimes the map function being faster, but neither was ever faster by a large margin. I'd encourage you to do your own measurements, but it seems that there's virtually no performance difference between the two, at least for accessing a single field via pattern matching. As the number of fields increases, though, the difference in performance becomes more apparent: for 10 fields, maps are slower by about 0.5%, and for 50 fields, maps are slower by about 50%. But as I stated up front, I see this as being immaterial, since if you're trying to use records and maps interchangeably you're doing it wrong.

*UPDATE: based on the conversation in the comments I clarified the answer to discuss performance differences as the number of fields/keys increases, and to point out that records and maps are not meant to be interchangeable.*

*UPDATE: for Erlang/OTP 24 the [Erlang Efficiency Guide](https://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/users_guide.html) was augmented with a [chapter on maps](https://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/maps.html) that's worth reading for detailed answers to this question.*

Comment: Geezus.  Nice answer.

Comment: Note that this only benchmarks structures with only one element. Maps, changes implementation to a HAMT when they grow large enough.

Comment: @AdamLindberg yes, I specifically mentioned at the end that this is for the case of single field access via pattern matching. I chose not to try to cover the "large number of fields" case because in practice records aren't used that way.

Comment: Maps are slower. With a record you know exactly which element of the tuple you want, this is decided a compile-time, while with a map you have to search the map to find the key. Irrespective of what algorithm is used to implement the map this is slower.

Comment: @rvirding yes for the general case, but again I was specific in my answer to note that it focuses on the single field case, with an eye towards practicality. Records and maps are not meant to be completely interchangeable, and having a record with a lot of fields isn't common. If you repeat my measurements with records and maps with 10 fields, maps are only about 0.5% slower, but put 50 fields in each and maps are slower by about 50%. But at that point, IMO it's an apple/oranges comparison, plus the likelihood of any this being an actual bottleneck in an actual production system is very low.

Answer (score 0):

I have different results when repeat the test with Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.6].

Disassembled code is different for r/1:

The record lookup is 1.5+ times faster.

```
{function, r, 1, 2}.
  {label,1}.
    {line,[{location,"f2.erl",9}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,f2},{atom,r},1}.
  {label,2}.
    {test,is_tagged_tuple,{f,1},[{x,0},2,{atom,foo}]}.
    {get_tuple_element,{x,0},1,{x,0}}.
    return.

{function, m, 1, 4}.
  {label,3}.
    {line,[{location,"f2.erl",12}]}.
    {func_info,{atom,f2},{atom,m},1}.
  {label,4}.
    {test,is_map,{f,3},[{x,0}]}.
    {get_map_elements,{f,3},{x,0},{list,[{atom,f},{x,1}]}}.
    {move,{x,1},{x,0}}.
    return.


9> lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f2,call_r,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
234309.04
10> lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f2,call_m,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
341411.9

After I declared -compile({inline, [r/1, m/1]}).

13> lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f2,call_r,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
199978.9
14> lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f2,call_m,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
356002.48
```

Answer (score 0):

I compared record with 10 elements to map of the same size. In this case records proved to be more than 2 times faster.

```
-module(f22).

-compile({inline, [r/1, m/1]}).

-export([call_r/1, call_r/2, call_m/1, call_m/2]).

-define(I, '2').
-define(V,  2 ).

-record(foo, {
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    '0'
    }).

r(#foo{?I = X}) ->
    X.

m(#{?I := X}) ->
    X.

call_r(N) ->
    call_r(#foo{
    '1' = 1,
    '2' = 2,
    '3' = 3,
    '4' = 4,
    '5' = 5,
    '6' = 6,
    '7' = 7,
    '8' = 8,
    '9' = 9,
    '0' = 0
    }, N).
call_r(_,0) ->
    ok;
call_r(F,N) ->
    ?V = r(F),
    call_r(F,N-1).

call_m(N) ->
    call_m(#{
    '1' => 1,
    '2' => 2,
    '3' => 3,
    '4' => 4,
    '5' => 5,
    '6' => 6,
    '7' => 7,
    '8' => 8,
    '9' => 9,
    '0' => 0
    }, N).
call_m(_,0) ->
    ok;
call_m(F,N) ->
    ?V = m(F),
    call_m(F,N-1).


% lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f22,call_r,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
% 229777.3
% lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f22,call_m,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
% 395897.68

% After declaring 
% -compile({inline, [r/1, m/1]}).
% lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f22,call_r,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
% 130859.98
% lists:sum([element(1,timer:tc(f22,call_m,[10000000])) || _ <- lists:seq(1,50)])/50.
% 306490.6
% 306490.6 / 130859.98 .
% 2.34212629407401
```